# getting the sort keys from a hash

Tags: perl, hash

This is the data dumper of \%spec_hash.
It is sorted by group which is a national exchange - and symbol.

```
foohost:~/walt $ vi  /tmp/footoo
$VAR1 = {
          'ARCX' => {
                      'IACI' => 1,
                      'MCHP' => 1,
                    },
          'AMXO' => {
                      'YUM' => 1,
                      'SYK' => 1,
                    },
          'XISX' => {
                      'FCEL' => 1,
                      'GPS' => 1,
                    }
        };
```

I was trying to sort by keys these two hashes but cannot. For debugging purposes I really want to see what is getting pumped out of these hashes

```
foreach my $exch (sort keys %spec_hash) {
foreach my $exch (sort keys %{$spec_hash{$exch}}) {
```

If I comment out the dumper and try a regular sort :

```
#print Dumper(\%spec_hash) ;

foreach my $exch (sort keys %spec_hash) {
#foreach my $exch (sort keys %{$spec_hash{$exch}}) {
    print "key: $exch, value: $spec_hash{$exch}\n"
    }
```

this i what I get :

```
key: AMXO, value: HASH(0x9cc88a4)
key: ARCX, value: HASH(0x9cd6f1c)
key: XISX, value: HASH(0x9cbd5f0)
```

and trying to print this prints nothing at all :

```
foreach my $exch (sort keys %{$spec_hash{$exch}}) {
    print "key: $exch, value: $spec_hash{$exch}\n"
    }
```

Comment: What's wrong with `foreach my $exch (sort keys %spec_hash) { ... }` ?

Comment: edited the above - it prints out a hex value  - - "key: AMXO, value: HASH(0x9cc88a4)" -

Comment: In your last statement, you are using `$exch` twice, as both the new iterator and your old value.  `foreach my $exch (sort keys %{$spec_hash{$exch}}) {`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly,

```
for my $exch (sort keys %spec_hash) {
   for my $sym (sort keys %{ $spec_hash{$exch} }) {
      print "Exchange: $exch, Symbol: $sym\n";
   }
}
```

You want to loop over every symbol, but they are grouped by exchange, so you must first loop over the exchanges.

Comment: This works - and I have not idea why, or how you figured it out.

Answer (score 0):

[`Data::Dumper`](http://perldoc.perl.org/Data/Dumper.html) doesn't sort its output by default.

Try adding [`$Data::Dumper::Sortkeys = 1;`](http://perldoc.perl.org/Data/Dumper.html#Configuration-Variables-or-Methods) to your script.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dumper;

my %hash = (
    'ARCX' => { 'IACI' => 1, 'MCHP' => 1, },
    'AMXO' => { 'YUM'  => 1, 'SYK'  => 1, },
    'XISX' => { 'FCEL' => 1, 'GPS'  => 1, },
);

print do {
    local $Data::Dumper::Sortkeys = 1;
    Dumper \%hash;
};
```

Outputs:

```
$VAR1 = {
          'AMXO' => {
                      'SYK' => 1,
                      'YUM' => 1
                    },
          'ARCX' => {
                      'IACI' => 1,
                      'MCHP' => 1
                    },
          'XISX' => {
                      'FCEL' => 1,
                      'GPS' => 1
                    }
        };
```

Note: This can be modified to include a sort subroutine that you define